# Add Progress Bar To Unzip Process

Tags: android

I have an unzip class I used from a tutorial site, works fine but I would like to add a progress bar to the unzipping process, I googled for some source code but I don't know where in the class I should put it. This is the decompress.java class:

```
    import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream; 

/** 
 * 
 * @author jon 
 */ 
public class Decompress { 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location; 

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location; 

    _dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
    Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

    if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
      _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
    } else { 
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
      for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
        fout.write(c); 
      } 

      zin.closeEntry(); 
      fout.close(); 
    } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(_location + dir); 

    if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

And I call it this way in my activity:

```
Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation);
d.unzip()
```

Comment: Looks like you are too lazy to do something by yourself. You found an unzipping code, and now you want somebody to make it to show progress instead of you?

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

**1.**

```
Decompress d = new Decompress(CurrentActivity.this,zipFile, unzipLocation);
d.unzip();
```

**2.**

```
Activity _activity;
        private String _zipFile; 
        private String _location; 
        ProgressDialog progressDialog =null;
        public Decompress(Activity activity,String zipFile, String location) { 
            _zipFile = zipFile; 
            _location = location; 
            this._activity = activity;
            _dirChecker(""); 
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        } 








public void unzip() { 
        try  { 
            progressDialog.show(); // Showing Progress Dialog 
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
            ZipEntry ze = null; 
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 

                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

                if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
                } else { 
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
                        fout.write(c); 
                    } 

                    zin.closeEntry(); 
                    fout.close(); 
                } 

            } 
            progressDialog.cancel(); // cancelling Dialog.
            zin.close(); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            progressDialog.cancel();
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
        } 

    } 

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
        File f = new File(_location + dir); 

        if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
            f.mkdirs(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The progress bar is not showing, I am not sure where the problem could be